# CREATE 5 TABLES WITH SQLITE AND ANDROID

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i have a problem with my Database, i want to CREATE 5 tables, but only first table (datos) is create. my Code is:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class AdaptadorDB {
    //BASE DE DATOS Y TABLAS
    public static final String NOMBRE_BD = "muebleria";
    public static final String TABLA_DATOS = "datos";
    public static final String TABLA_EMPRESAS = "empresas";
    public static final String TABLA_COBRADORES = "cobradores";
    public static final String TABLA_PAGOS = "pagos";
    public static final String TABLA_ARTICULOS = "articulos";

    //CAMPOS DE TABLAS
    public static final String nFILA_ID = "_id";
    public static final String cCLIENTE = "cliente";
    public static final String cNOMBRE = "nombre";
    public static final String cDIRECCION = "direccion";
    public static final String cCOLONIA = "colonia";
    public static final String nFACTURA = "factura";
    public static final String nEMPRESA = "empresa";
    public static final String nTOTAL = "total";
    public static final String nSALDO = "saldo";
    public static final String nINTERESES = "intereses";
    public static final String nRUTA = "ruta";
    public static final String nCOBRADOR = "cobrador";
    public static final String cEMPRESA = "nomempresa";
    public static final String nTIPOEMP = "tipoempresa";
    public static final String cCOBRADOR = "nomcobrador";
    public static final String cFECHA = "fecha";
    public static final String nPAGO = "pago";
    public static final String cHORA = "hora";
    public static final String cARTICULO = "articulo";
    public static final String nCANTIDAD = "cantidad";
    public static final String nFACTURAS = "numfacturas";
    public static final String nABONO = "abono";


    //VERSION DE BASE DE DATOS
    public static final int VERSION_BD = 6;

    //MANEJADORES DE LA BASE DE DATOS Y CONTEXTO.
    private Context context;
    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;


    public AdaptadorDB(Context ctx) {
        this.context= ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, NOMBRE_BD, null, VERSION_BD);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String CREAR_DATOS = "create table datos ("+nFILA_ID+" integer "
                    +"primary key autoincrement, "
                    +cCLIENTE+" text not null,  "+cNOMBRE+" text not null,  "
                    +cDIRECCION+" text not null, "+cCOLONIA+" text not null, "
                    +nFACTURA+" integer not null, "+nEMPRESA+" integer not null, "
                    +nTOTAL+" real not null, "+nSALDO+" real not null, "
                    +nINTERESES+" real not null, "+nRUTA+" integer not null, "
                    +nCOBRADOR+" integer not null, "+nFACTURAS+" integer not null, "
                    +nABONO+" real not null);";
            String CREAR_INDICE_NOMBRE = "create index nombre on datos ("+cNOMBRE+" asc);";
            String CREAR_INDICE_CLIENTE = "create index cliente on datos ("+cCLIENTE+" asc);";


            String CREAR_EMPRESAS = "create table empresas ("+nFILA_ID+" integer "
                    +" primary key autoincrment, "
                    +nEMPRESA+" integer not null, "+cEMPRESA+" text not null, "
                    +nTIPOEMP+" integer not null);";
            String CREAR_INDICE_EMPRESA = "create index empresa on empresas ("+nEMPRESA+" asc);";

            String CREAR_COBRADORES = "create table cobradores ("+nFILA_ID+" integer"
                    +" primary key autoincrement, "
                    +nCOBRADOR+" integer not null, "+cCOBRADOR+" text not null);";
            String CREAR_INDICE_COBRADORES = "create index cobrador on cobradores ("+nCOBRADOR+" asc);";

            String CREAR_PAGOS = "create table pagos ("+nFILA_ID+" integer"
                    +"primary key autoincrement, "+cFECHA+" text not null, "
                    +cCLIENTE+" text not null, "+nPAGO+" real not null, "
                    +cHORA+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+ nFACTURA + " integer not null);";
            String CREAR_INDICE_FECHAPAGO = "create index fecha on pagos ("+cFECHA+" asc);";

            String CREAR_ARTICULOS = "crea table articulos ("+nFILA_ID+" integer " 
                    +"primary key autoincrement "
                    +cCLIENTE+" text not null, "+nFACTURA+" integer not null, "
                    +cARTICULO+" text not null, "+nCANTIDAD+" integer not null);";
            String CREAR_INDICE_ARTICULOS = "create index articulo on articulos ("+cARTICULO+");";


            try {

                db.execSQL(CREAR_DATOS);
                db.execSQL(CREAR_INDICE_NOMBRE);
                db.execSQL(CREAR_INDICE_CLIENTE);

                db.execSQL(CREAR_EMPRESAS);
                db.execSQL(CREAR_INDICE_EMPRESA);

                db.execSQL(CREAR_COBRADORES);
                db.execSQL(CREAR_INDICE_COBRADORES);

                db.execSQL(CREAR_PAGOS);
                db.execSQL(CREAR_INDICE_FECHAPAGO);

                db.execSQL(CREAR_ARTICULOS);
                db.execSQL(CREAR_INDICE_ARTICULOS);

            } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS datos");
            db.execSQL("DROP INDEX IF EXISTS nombre");
            db.execSQL("DROP INDEX IF EXISTS cliente");

            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS empresas");
            db.execSQL("DROP INDEX IF EXISTS empresa");

            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cobradores");
            db.execSQL("DROP INDEX IF EXISTS cobrador");

            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pagos");
            db.execSQL("DROP INDEX IF EXISTS fecha");

            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS articulos");
            db.execSQL("DROP INDEX IF EXISTS articulo");
            onCreate(db);

        }

    }
```

and here id where i call my DB to insert data, only in the "datos" table the data is inserted, in the other 4 tables not. I export the DB to my PC and with sqlite 3 only can see the "datos" table.

```
    AdaptadorDB base = new AdaptadorDB(this);
    DatosDto datos = new DatosDto();
    base.abrir();
    long res = base.insertarDatos();
    base.cerrar();
    Toast.makeText(this, res+" ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and this is how i test the inserts in tables.

```
public long insertarDatos() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (db != null) {

            long res1, res2, res3, res4, res5;

            try {

                ContentValues cvdatos = new ContentValues();

                cvdatos.put(cCLIENTE, "C0001");
                cvdatos.put(cNOMBRE, "ARIEL WOOLFOLK VELEZ");
                cvdatos.put(cDIRECCION, "AV. DEL SUR #9476");
                cvdatos.put(cCOLONIA, "LA GALERA");
                cvdatos.put(nFACTURA, 12);
                cvdatos.put(nEMPRESA, 3);
                cvdatos.put(nTOTAL, 7500.00);
                cvdatos.put(nSALDO, 8650.00);
                cvdatos.put(nINTERESES, 325.32);
                cvdatos.put(nRUTA, 20);
                cvdatos.put(nCOBRADOR, 5);
                cvdatos.put(nFACTURAS, 3);
                cvdatos.put(nABONO, 35.00);

                res1 = db.insert(TABLA_DATOS, null, cvdatos);

                cvdatos.put(cCLIENTE, "C0002");
                cvdatos.put(cNOMBRE, "CARLOS WOOLFOLK VELEZ");
                cvdatos.put(cDIRECCION, "JARDIN DE AZUCENAS #9476");
                cvdatos.put(cCOLONIA, "JARDINES UNIVERSIDAD");
                cvdatos.put(nFACTURA, 10);
                cvdatos.put(nEMPRESA, 1);
                cvdatos.put(nTOTAL, 4000.00);
                cvdatos.put(nSALDO, 2500.00);
                cvdatos.put(nINTERESES, 132.32);
                cvdatos.put(nRUTA, 40);
                cvdatos.put(nCOBRADOR, 1);
                cvdatos.put(nFACTURAS, 1);
                cvdatos.put(nABONO, 35.00);

                res1 = db.insert(TABLA_DATOS, null, cvdatos);

                cvdatos.put(cCLIENTE, "C0003");
                cvdatos.put(cNOMBRE, "JOSE ESPARZA FLORES");
                cvdatos.put(cDIRECCION, "IGNACIO RODRIGUEZ #9476");
                cvdatos.put(cCOLONIA, "MAGISTERIAL");
                cvdatos.put(nFACTURA, 11);
                cvdatos.put(nEMPRESA, 2);
                cvdatos.put(nTOTAL, 5000.00);
                cvdatos.put(nSALDO, 3500.00);
                cvdatos.put(nINTERESES, 232.32);
                cvdatos.put(nRUTA, 30);
                cvdatos.put(nCOBRADOR, 2);
                cvdatos.put(nFACTURAS, 2);
                cvdatos.put(nABONO, 45.00);

                res1 = db.insert(TABLA_DATOS, null, cvdatos);

                cvdatos.put(cCLIENTE, "C0004");
                cvdatos.put(cNOMBRE, "IVAN PALAFOX CRUZ");
                cvdatos.put(cDIRECCION, "ROBERTO MISTRAL #9476");
                cvdatos.put(cCOLONIA, "DEL LEONL");
                cvdatos.put(nFACTURA, 14);
                cvdatos.put(nEMPRESA, 3);
                cvdatos.put(nTOTAL, 6000.00);
                cvdatos.put(nSALDO, 4500.00);
                cvdatos.put(nINTERESES, 332.32);
                cvdatos.put(nRUTA, 10);
                cvdatos.put(nCOBRADOR, 3);
                cvdatos.put(nFACTURAS, 3);
                cvdatos.put(nABONO, 55.00);

                res1 = db.insert(TABLA_DATOS, null, cvdatos);




                ContentValues cvempresas = new ContentValues();

                cvempresas.put(nEMPRESA, 1);
                cvempresas.put(cEMPRESA, "MUEBLES Y MAS");
                cvempresas.put(nTIPOEMP, 1);

                res2 = db.insert(TABLA_EMPRESAS, null, cvempresas);

                cvempresas.put(nEMPRESA, 2);
                cvempresas.put(cEMPRESA, "PRESTAMOS");
                cvempresas.put(nTIPOEMP, 2);

                res2 = db.insert(TABLA_EMPRESAS, null, cvempresas);

                cvempresas.put(nEMPRESA, 3);
                cvempresas.put(cEMPRESA, "PRESTAMOS EN EFECTIVO");
                cvempresas.put(nTIPOEMP, 2);

                res2 = db.insert(TABLA_EMPRESAS, null, cvempresas);



                ContentValues cvcobradores = new ContentValues();

                cvcobradores.put(nCOBRADOR, 1);
                cvcobradores.put(cCOBRADOR, "LUIS MARTINEZ");
                res3 = db.insert(TABLA_COBRADORES, null, cvcobradores);

                cvcobradores.put(nCOBRADOR, 2);
                cvcobradores.put(cCOBRADOR, "JUAN RODRIGUEZ");
                res3 = db.insert(TABLA_COBRADORES, null, cvcobradores);

                cvcobradores.put(nCOBRADOR, 3);
                cvcobradores.put(cCOBRADOR, "CARLOS SEPULVEDA");
                res3 = db.insert(TABLA_COBRADORES, null, cvcobradores);

                cvcobradores.put(nCOBRADOR, 4);
                cvcobradores.put(cCOBRADOR, "MARIO RUIZ");
                res3 = db.insert(TABLA_COBRADORES, null, cvcobradores);



                ContentValues cvpagos = new ContentValues();

                DatePicker dia = new DatePicker(context);
                TimePicker hora = new TimePicker(context);

                cvpagos.put(cFECHA, dia.getDayOfMonth()+"/"+dia.getMonth()+"/"+dia.getYear());
                cvpagos.put(cCLIENTE, "C0001");
                cvpagos.put(nPAGO, 100.00);
                cvpagos.put(cHORA, hora.getCurrentHour()+":"+hora.getCurrentMinute()+":");
                cvpagos.put(nFACTURA, 12);

                res4 = db.insert(TABLA_PAGOS, null, cvpagos);

                cvpagos.put(cFECHA, dia.getDayOfMonth()+"/"+dia.getMonth()+"/"+dia.getYear());
                cvpagos.put(cCLIENTE, "C0003");
                cvpagos.put(nPAGO, 200.00);
                cvpagos.put(cHORA, hora.getCurrentHour()+":"+hora.getCurrentMinute()+":");
                cvpagos.put(nFACTURA, 11);

                res4 = db.insert(TABLA_PAGOS, null, cvpagos);

                cvpagos.put(cFECHA, dia.getDayOfMonth()+"/"+dia.getMonth()+"/"+dia.getYear());
                cvpagos.put(cCLIENTE, "C0004");
                cvpagos.put(nPAGO, 300.00);
                cvpagos.put(cHORA, hora.getCurrentHour()+":"+hora.getCurrentMinute()+":");
                cvpagos.put(nFACTURA, 14);

                res4 = db.insert(TABLA_PAGOS, null, cvpagos);

                cvpagos.put(cFECHA, dia.getDayOfMonth()+"/"+dia.getMonth()+"/"+dia.getYear());
                cvpagos.put(cCLIENTE, "C0002");
                cvpagos.put(nPAGO, 400.00);
                cvpagos.put(cHORA, hora.getCurrentHour()+":"+hora.getCurrentMinute()+":");
                cvpagos.put(nFACTURA, 11);

                res4 = db.insert(TABLA_PAGOS, null, cvpagos);



                ContentValues cvarticulos = new ContentValues();

                cvarticulos.put(cCLIENTE, "C0004");
                cvarticulos.put(nFACTURA, 14);
                cvarticulos.put(cARTICULO, "COLCHON COMFORT");
                cvarticulos.put(nCANTIDAD, 2);

                res5 = db.insert(TABLA_ARTICULOS, null, cvarticulos);

                cvarticulos.put(cCLIENTE, "C0002");
                cvarticulos.put(nFACTURA, 10);
                cvarticulos.put(cARTICULO, "BASE DE MADERA");
                cvarticulos.put(nCANTIDAD, 2);

                res5 = db.insert(TABLA_ARTICULOS, null, cvarticulos);

                cvarticulos.put(cCLIENTE, "C0003");
                cvarticulos.put(nFACTURA, 11);
                cvarticulos.put(cARTICULO, "MESA PRINCESS");
                cvarticulos.put(nCANTIDAD, 1);

                res5 = db.insert(TABLA_ARTICULOS, null, cvarticulos);

                cvarticulos.put(cCLIENTE, "C0004");
                cvarticulos.put(nFACTURA, 14);
                cvarticulos.put(cARTICULO, "SILLA PRINCESS");
                cvarticulos.put(nCANTIDAD, 4);

                res5 = db.insert(TABLA_ARTICULOS, null, cvarticulos);

                Toast.makeText(context, res1+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(context, res2+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(context, res3+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(context, res4+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(context, res5+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return 0;
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return 0;
        }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Base no creada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return 0;
        }
}
```

i already change the Version, but nothing happend, only the "datos" table is create but "empresas", "cobradores", "pagos" and "articulos" doesnt. Can someone helpme and see where is the error?.

thanks in advance.

PS Sorry if my English its not so well :)

Comment: I would convert all your string to one real string (in an error log, logcat etc), and then check it for syntax. Dowload something that understands sqllite and try if it actually works there. If it doesn't, you've found your problem (the sql itself). If it _does_ work in there, the problem is not with the sql: you can make the example smaller (make 2 very tiny tables, but still having your problem), so it is easier to spot the error. Then put that code in your question, instead of this big blurp :)

Comment: @user2881413 Do you get any error in your logcat ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your one query you have written wrong spelling of `increment` check out

Instead of this:

```
  String CREAR_EMPRESAS = "create table empresas ("+nFILA_ID+" integer "
                    +" primary key autoincrment, "
                    +nEMPRESA+" integer not null, "+cEMPRESA+" text not null, "
                    +nTIPOEMP+" integer not null);";
```

Do this :

```
  String CREAR_EMPRESAS = "create table empresas ("+nFILA_ID+" integer "
                    +" primary key autoincrement, " //Correct spelling
                    +nEMPRESA+" integer not null, "+cEMPRESA+" text not null, "
                    +nTIPOEMP+" integer not null);";
```

Also in your query you have not properly written `create` :

```
 String CREAR_ARTICULOS = "crea table articulos ("+nFILA_ID+" integer " 
                    +"primary key autoincrement "
                    +cCLIENTE+" text not null, "+nFACTURA+" integer not null, "
                    +cARTICULO+" text not null, "+nCANTIDAD+" integer not null);";
```

Write as below:

```
 String CREAR_ARTICULOS = "create table articulos ("+nFILA_ID+" integer " 
                    +"primary key autoincrement "
                    +cCLIENTE+" text not null, "+nFACTURA+" integer not null, "
                    +cARTICULO+" text not null, "+nCANTIDAD+" integer not null);";
```

There are so many mistakes in your queries. I have changed relevant code in your class so try out with below code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class AdaptadorDB {
    // BASE DE DATOS Y TABLAS
    public static final String NOMBRE_BD = "muebleria.db";
    public static final String TABLA_DATOS = "datos";
    public static final String TABLA_EMPRESAS = "empresas";
    public static final String TABLA_COBRADORES = "cobradores";
    public static final String TABLA_PAGOS = "pagos";
    public static final String TABLA_ARTICULOS = "articulos";

    // CAMPOS DE TABLAS
    public static final String nFILA_ID = "_id";
    public static final String cCLIENTE = "cliente";
    public static final String cNOMBRE = "nombre";
    public static final String cDIRECCION = "direccion";
    public static final String cCOLONIA = "colonia";
    public static final String nFACTURA = "factura";
    public static final String nEMPRESA = "empresa";
    public static final String nTOTAL = "total";
    public static final String nSALDO = "saldo";
    public static final String nINTERESES = "intereses";
    public static final String nRUTA = "ruta";
    public static final String nCOBRADOR = "cobrador";
    public static final String cEMPRESA = "nomempresa";
    public static final String nTIPOEMP = "tipoempresa";
    public static final String cCOBRADOR = "nomcobrador";
    public static final String cFECHA = "fecha";
    public static final String nPAGO = "pago";
    public static final String cHORA = "hora";
    public static final String cARTICULO = "articulo";
    public static final String nCANTIDAD = "cantidad";
    public static final String nFACTURAS = "numfacturas";
    public static final String nABONO = "abono";

    // VERSION DE BASE DE DATOS
    public static final int VERSION_BD = 6;

    // MANEJADORES DE LA BASE DE DATOS Y CONTEXTO.
    private Context context;
    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    private static final String CREAR_DATOS = "create table datos (" + nFILA_ID
            + " integer " + "primary key autoincrement, " + cCLIENTE
            + " text not null,  " + cNOMBRE + " text not null,  " + cDIRECCION
            + " text not null, " + cCOLONIA + " text not null, " + nFACTURA
            + " integer not null, " + nEMPRESA + " integer not null, " + nTOTAL
            + " real not null, " + nSALDO + " real not null, " + nINTERESES
            + " real not null, " + nRUTA + " integer not null, " + nCOBRADOR
            + " integer not null, " + nFACTURAS + " integer not null, "
            + nABONO + " real not null);";
    private static final String CREAR_INDICE_NOMBRE = "create index nombre on datos ("
            + cNOMBRE + " asc);";
    private static final String CREAR_INDICE_CLIENTE = "create index cliente on datos ("
            + cCLIENTE + " asc);";

    private static final String CREAR_EMPRESAS = "create table empresas ("
            + nFILA_ID + " integer " + " primary key autoincrement, "
            + nEMPRESA + " integer not null, " + cEMPRESA + " text not null, "
            + nTIPOEMP + " integer not null);";
    private static final String CREAR_INDICE_EMPRESA = "create index empresa on empresas ("
            + nEMPRESA + " asc);";

    private static final String CREAR_COBRADORES = "create table cobradores ("
            + nFILA_ID + " integer" + " primary key autoincrement, "
            + nCOBRADOR + " integer not null, " + cCOBRADOR
            + " text not null);";
    private static final String CREAR_INDICE_COBRADORES = "create index cobrador on cobradores ("
            + nCOBRADOR + " asc);";

    private static final String CREAR_PAGOS = "create table pagos (" + nFILA_ID
            + " integer " + "primary key autoincrement, " + cFECHA
            + " text not null, " + cCLIENTE + " text not null, " + nPAGO
            + " real not null, " + cHORA + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + nFACTURA
            + " integer not null);";
    private static final String CREAR_INDICE_FECHAPAGO = "create index fecha on pagos ("
            + cFECHA + " asc);";

    private static final String CREAR_ARTICULOS = "create table articulos ("
            + nFILA_ID + " integer " + "primary key autoincrement ," + cCLIENTE
            + " text not null, " + nFACTURA + " integer not null, " + cARTICULO
            + " text not null, " + nCANTIDAD + " integer not null);";
    private static final String CREAR_INDICE_ARTICULOS = "create index articulo on articulos ("
            + cARTICULO + ");";

    public AdaptadorDB(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;

        if ((null == db) || (!db.isOpen())) {
            db = context.openOrCreateDatabase(NOMBRE_BD, 0, null);

            try {

                db.execSQL(CREAR_DATOS);
                db.execSQL(CREAR_INDICE_NOMBRE);
                db.execSQL(CREAR_INDICE_CLIENTE);

                db.execSQL(CREAR_EMPRESAS);
                db.execSQL(CREAR_INDICE_EMPRESA);

                db.execSQL(CREAR_COBRADORES);
                db.execSQL(CREAR_INDICE_COBRADORES);

                db.execSQL(CREAR_PAGOS);
                db.execSQL(CREAR_INDICE_FECHAPAGO);

                db.execSQL(CREAR_ARTICULOS);
                db.execSQL(CREAR_INDICE_ARTICULOS);

            } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, NOMBRE_BD, null, VERSION_BD);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {

                db.execSQL(CREAR_DATOS);
                db.execSQL(CREAR_INDICE_NOMBRE);
                db.execSQL(CREAR_INDICE_CLIENTE);

                db.execSQL(CREAR_EMPRESAS);
                db.execSQL(CREAR_INDICE_EMPRESA);

                db.execSQL(CREAR_COBRADORES);
                db.execSQL(CREAR_INDICE_COBRADORES);

                db.execSQL(CREAR_PAGOS);
                db.execSQL(CREAR_INDICE_FECHAPAGO);

                db.execSQL(CREAR_ARTICULOS);
                db.execSQL(CREAR_INDICE_ARTICULOS);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS datos");
        db.execSQL("DROP INDEX IF EXISTS nombre");
        db.execSQL("DROP INDEX IF EXISTS cliente");

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS empresas");
        db.execSQL("DROP INDEX IF EXISTS empresa");

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cobradores");
        db.execSQL("DROP INDEX IF EXISTS cobrador");

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pagos");
        db.execSQL("DROP INDEX IF EXISTS fecha");

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS articulos");
        db.execSQL("DROP INDEX IF EXISTS articulo");
        onCreate(db);

    }

}
}
```

Comment: Welcome :) And make sure you do not make such a silly mistakes again. :) All the best.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is DONT WRITE sqlLite code, let other frameworks deal whit this problem. Use GreenDAO, this is a eficient way to reach your goal using only objects.(Its like JPA-Hibernate).

[GreenDAO link](http://greendao-orm.com/)